# Multiple Backgroundworker threads in a single Backgroundworker thread

Tags: multithreading, backgroundworker, restore

I have an issue here with multi-threading.  Tried using both backgroundworker and threads.

**Objective:** Select an item from a combo-box and click a button to trigger multiple backup file restores into the MSSQL Server.  The intention is to popup as many popups as there are Backup files to restore. The main window starts a backgroundworker, showing the overall progress, while the child threads result in non-modal child popups representing each restoration process with progress.  This works fine if run serially (without threads/backgroundworker).  My intention is to run a bunch of parallel popups, so that the restoration is much more quick.

**Problem Statement:**  My intention is to run a bunch of parallel popups, so that the restoration is much more quick instead of running serially. While trying to debug, its a chaotic break-point show that the Visual Studio shows up (perhaps to represent multiple threads in parallel).  But the ultimate goal is not being achieved.  Can anybody help me in this regard?

**- Code Extracts**

Here is the code extract, which I've done and this works in a serial fashion.  But as soon as I put the code for multi-threading, nothing works.  Only the popups appear, but no processing happens.

This is the button click event, which starts the whole process

```
private void btnSnapshot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetPanelEnabledProperty(false); // Disable All Controls on the main window

            // Select the text against which the DATABASE Backup Files are to be picked
            // Start the main background worker process, which in turn will trigger few other child threads
            BGWrk.RunWorkerAsync(2000);

            BGWrk.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BGWrk_DoWork);
            BGWrk.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(BGWrk_ProgressChanged);
            BGWrk.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler
                                (BGWrk_RunWorkerCompleted);
            BackgroundWorker helperBW = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            BGWrk.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            BGWrk.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        }

        private void BGWrk_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker helperBW = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            int arg = (int)e.Argument;
            //Call the method that invokes the popup window instances in a loop, for each file found for the SnapShotName selected in the combobox
            ParallelRestoreSnapshot();

            if (helperBW.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

        }

        // This method will create backgroundworker instances and in turn the Do_Work events of those backgroundworkers will call the popup against each backup file.
        private bool ParallelRestoreSnapshot()
        {
            FileOperations FIO = new FileOperations();

            if (SelectedSnapShot != null && SelectedSnapShot != "None")
            {
                string[] sBakFiles;
                sBakFiles = FIO.GetListOfBackupFiles(sEntireBackupFilePath);

                try
                {
                    progressPopupsList = new List<FrmProgressPopup>();

                    for (int aIndex = 0; aIndex < sBakFiles.Length; aIndex++)
                    {
                        BackgroundWorker bgPopups = new BackgroundWorker();

                        BAKFileName = sBakFiles[aIndex];

                        bgPopups.RunWorkerAsync(2000);
                        bgPopups.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgPopups_DoWork);
                        bgPopups.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgPopups_ProgressChanged);
                        bgPopups.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler
                                            (bgPopups_RunWorkerCompleted);

                        bgPopups.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                        bgPopups.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                    }
                    retVal = true;
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error while Restoring: " + exc.Message, "Exception encountered", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    //goto NextDB;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            FIO = null;
            return retVal;
        }

// This DoWork event calls a method GeneratePopupInstances which makes copies of a window, which is shown as non-modal

         private void bgPopups_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker helperBW = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            int arg = (int)e.Argument;
            //BackgroundProcessLogicMethod(helperBW, arg);
            GeneratePopupInstances();
            if (helperBW.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

        }
```